# Image choppy on scroll with Chrome and Safari (Not firefox)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, scroll, safari

I have a problem with my wordpress website. All the Images are choppy when i scroll down the page on Chrome and Safari, but the result it is very good and smooth on Firefox.

Here is my website : http://matieresetcouleurs.ch/

For you to compare, here is the kind of website i want, and the images are not choppy on this one : http://www.dcube.swiss/

Do you have any clues of what the problem can be ?

Thanks for your help.

Jules

Answer (score 0):

I am not having any scroll issues...either your computer memory is not enough or internet problems. Perhaps empty your browser cache for chrome and internet explorer.
Also optimise your images to make sure they are not big filesize.

Comment: This is more suitable for a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: It's ok, i find a solution to my problem. Thanks a lot for taking the time to have a look !